# Memory optimization in sencha - phonegap app

Tags: javascript, list, memory-management, cordova, extjs

Is there any tutorials that describes the best practices for memory optimization techniques in Sencha?

Thanks
Arun A G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be these articles will help you:

- [Sencha Touch: Performance Optimization](http://www.senchatouchbits.com/10/performance-optimization.html)
- [Sencha Touch: Optimizing Memory Usage](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-optimizing-memory-usage/)
- [Performance tips for device](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494809/Performance-tips-for-device/)